# Error: not a data name en programa cobol

Tags: cobol

Tengo un programa que ordena tablas, pero no sé por qué en `recorrer-tabla` se me subraya en rojo y dice "not a data name". En cambio, si lo ubico unas lineas más arriba lo toma, pero no hace lo q pido q es ordenar la tabla.

Éste es mi código:

```
program-id. Program1 as "ConsoleApplication2.Program1".

   data division

   working-storage section.
   01 tabla         pic 99 occurs 20
            indexed by indice.
   01 hora.
   05  filler           pic 9(6).
   05  hx           pic 99.

   01 variable-aux          pic 99.
   01 variable-paso     pic 99.

   procedure division.  

      set indice to 1
      perform rellenar-tabla until indice > 20
      set indice to 1
      perform display-tabla until indice > 20

      move 1 to variable-aux
      perform ordenar-numeros until variable-aux > 20
      stop ' '
      display '--------------------------------'
      set indice to 1
      perform display-tabla until indice > 20
      perform recorrer-tabla until indice > 20
      set indice to 1
      stop ' '

      goback.

   rellenar-tabla.
      display spaces upon crt
      display ' ' line 01 column 05
      accept hora from time
      move hx to tabla(indice)
      set indice up by 1
      display hx line 02 column 05
      stop ' '.

   display-tabla.
      display tabla(indice)
      set indice up by 1.

   ordenar-numeros.
      set indice to variable-aux
      perform recorrer-tabla until indice > 20
      add 1 to variable-aux
   recorrer-tabla.
       if tabla(variable-aux) > tabla(indice)
           move tabla(variable-aux) to variable-paso
           move tabla(indice) to variable-paso
           move variable-paso to tabla(indice)
         end-if
         set indice up by 1.


   end program Program1.
```

Answer (score 3):

No estás cerrando el `ordenar-numeros` con el punto.

Por eso `recorrer-tabla` te da error cuando está debajo de `ordenar-numeros` pero no falla cuando lo mueves unas líneas más arriba.

Answer (score 0):

**Especificaste un operando que no es un elemento de datos donde se espera un elemento de datos válido.** Por ejemplo, es posible que hayas especificado un nombre FD o un nombre de condición en lugar de un nombre de datos.

Comment: Esta respuesta no identifica el problema y entrega una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta un punto para terminar el párrafo:

```
   ordenar-numeros.
      set indice to variable-aux
      perform recorrer-tabla until indice > 20
      add 1 to variable-aux

   recorrer-tabla.
```

Probablemente el compilador está leyendo

```
add 1 to variable-aux recorrer-tabla.
```

o sea, lee que estas sumando 1 a variable-aux y a recorrer-table.

Agrega el punto que falta:

```
   ordenar-numeros.
      set indice to variable-aux
      perform recorrer-tabla until indice > 20
      add 1 to variable-aux.

   recorrer-tabla.
```